# How do I skip any number in range that has a 5 in it for ex 25 or 15?

Tags: python

```
 def no_6(l,h):
        for i in range(v,x):
            if i != 5:
                continue
            else:
                print(i)
        
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
  
        v = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
        x = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
```

How do I skip a number in a range that is in a for loop. I'm letting the user input the range and I want to skip any number with the number 5 in it ex regardless it is 5, 25, or 15  I want to skip it. Can I use floor division or modulo with my if statements to figure this out?

Comment: Numbers do not have 5s in them. *Decimal representations of* numbers have 5s in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
def no_6(l,h):
    for i in range(v,x):
        if str(i).find(str(5)) != -1:
            continue
        else:
            print(i)
v = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
x = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
no_6(v,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want numbers that are multiples of 5 (i.e. 5 is a factor), then you want to check their value modulo 5 (`% 5`).  If you want to check whether any digit is a 5, then I think turning it into a string and checking for that character is the easiest way.

```
>>> a = 15
>>> b = 42
>>> a % 5 == 0, b % 5 == 0
(True, False)
>>> "5" in str(a), "5" in str(b)
(True, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if i != 5:
```

To be:

```
if '5' in str(i):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension. If you want multiples of 5, then (assuming v=0 and x =25):

```
[i for i in range(v,x) if i % 5 == 0]

Out[1]: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Full code:

```
def no_6(l,h):
    print([i for i in range(v,x) if i % 5 == 0])

v = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
x = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
no_6(v,x)
```

And, if you need to print it all on a new line, rather than a list, then use:

```
def no_6(l,h):
    l = [i for i in range(v,x) if i%5 == 0]
    for i in l:
        print(i)


v = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
x = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
no_6(v,x)
```

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly but can I couldn't I use % and //?

Comment: If you use `//` that is "Floor", which means it rounds down to nearest integer. `%` is for remainder For example, `25 // 2` returns `12` while `25 % 2` returns `1`

Comment: Is it a way to code that using if statements because I can't figure it out?